# Calling instagram API without using callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am consuming the Instagram API through Angular. i am consuming it without authentication.

My code looks like below. Can anyone advise if this is the best way to call this API, by using a callback. Is there a better approach by using promises? If so how would this look? and also, how can I add an error handler to this code?

**factory.js**

```
app.factory('socialMedia', ['$http', function($http){
    return {
        fetchInstagram: function(callback){       
            var url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/*******/media/recent?client_id=*****&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
            $http.jsonp(url).success(function(response){
                callback(response.data);
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

**controller.js**

```
app.controller("instagramCtrl", ["socialMedia", function (socialMedia) {
    instagramCtrl = this;
    this.instagramPosts = [];   
    this.loading = true;

    socialMedia.fetchInstagram(function (data){
        instagramCtrl.loading = false;  
        for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
             instagramCtrl.instagramPosts.push(data[i]);
        }        
    });
}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `callbacks`, it's the past. `$http` service returns promise object, which is much more convenient option (error handling, promise chaining):

```
app.factory('socialMedia', ['$http', function($http){
    return {
        fetchInstagram: function() {       
            var url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/*******/media/recent?client_id=*****&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
            return $http.jsonp(url).then(function(response) {
                return response.data;
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Make sure you return Promise from `fetchInstagram` method.

Then in controller you would use it like this:

```
socialMedia.fetchInstagram().then(function(data) {
    $scope.data = data;
});
```

Comment: could you show how the fucntion should look like in the controller?